# Read all users from AD using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

Tags: c#, ldap

I need to read all users from the AD. Here is code that I am using:

```
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
using Novell.Directory.Ldap.Controls;
using System.Linq;

namespace LdapTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            LdapConnection ldapConn = new LdapConnection();
            ldapConn.SecureSocketLayer = true;
            ldapConn.Connect(HOST, PORT);

            try
            {
                var cntRead = 0;
                int? cntTotal = null;
                var curPage = 0;

                ldapConn.Bind(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

                do
                {
                    var constraints = new LdapSearchConstraints();
                    constraints.SetControls(new LdapControl[]
                    {
                        new LdapSortControl(new LdapSortKey("sn"), true),
                        new LdapVirtualListControl("sn=*", 0, 10)
                    });

                    ILdapSearchResults searchResults = ldapConn.Search(
                        "OU=All Users,DC=homecredit,DC=ru",
                        LdapConnection.ScopeSub,
                        "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))",
                        null,
                        false,
                        constraints
                    );

                    while (searchResults.HasMore() && ((cntTotal == null) || (cntRead < cntTotal)))
                    {
                        ++cntRead;

                        try
                        {
                            LdapEntry entry = searchResults.Next();
                        }
                        catch (LdapReferralException)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    ++curPage;
                    cntTotal = GetTotalCount(searchResults as LdapSearchResults);
                } while ((cntTotal != null) && (cntRead < cntTotal));
            }
            finally
            {
                ldapConn.Disconnect();
            }
        }

        private static int? GetTotalCount(LdapSearchResults results)
        {
            if (results.ResponseControls != null)
            {
                var r = (from c in results.ResponseControls
                         let d = c as LdapVirtualListResponse
                         where (d != null)
                         select (LdapVirtualListResponse)c).SingleOrDefault();
                if (r != null)
                {
                    return r.ContentCount;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I used this question [Page LDAP query against AD in .NET Core using Novell LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208799/page-ldap-query-against-ad-in-net-core-using-novell-ldap) as basis.
Unfortunatelly I get this exception when I am trying to recieve the very first entry:

```
"Unavailable Critical Extension"
000020EF: SvcErr: DSID-03140594, problem 5010 (UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could come from an control disabled on the server side. Could you try your code desactivating your `LdapSortControl`, then `LdapVirtualListControl`, then both to see what happens?

Comment: @MaxXapi Without line [new LdapVirtualListControl("sn=*", 0, 10)] it works. Does it mean that I cannot use LdapVirtualListControl? How can I get all 1000+ users from AD then?

Answer (score 1):

VLVs are browsing indexes and are not directly related to the possibility or not to browse large numbers of entries (see [generic documentation](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Virtual%20List%20View%20Control)). So even if this control would be activated on your AD, you wouldn't be able to retrieve more than 1000 elements this way :

- [how VLVs work on AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/searching-with-the-ldap-vlv-control)
- `MaxPageSize` is 1000 by default on AD (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/view-set-ldap-policy-using-ntdsutil))

So what you can do:

- use a specific paged results control, but it seems that the Novell C# LDAP library [does not have one](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/?page=/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/cnet/data/bow8fjp.html)
- ask you the question: "is this pertinent to look for all the users in a single request?" (your request looks like a batch request: remember that a LDAP server is not designed for the same purposes than a classic database - that can easily return millions of entries - and that's why most of LDAP directories have default size limits around 1000).

The answer is **no**: review your design, be more specific in your LDAP search filter, your search base, etc.

The answer is **yes**:

- you have a single AD server: ask your administrator to change the `MaxPageSize` value, but this setting is global and can lead to several side effects (ie. what happens if everybody start to request all the users all the time?)
- you have several AD servers: you can configure one for specific "batch like" queries like the one you're trying to do (so large `MaxPageSize`, large timeouts etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use approach described here:
https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/issues/71#issuecomment-420917269

The solution is far from being perfect but at least I am able to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 3.5 the library supports [Simple Paged Results Control](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control) - and the usage is as simple as `ldapConnection.SearchUsingSimplePaging(searchOptions, pageSize)` or `ldapConnection.SearchUsingSimplePaging(ldapEntryConverter, searchOptions, pageSize)` - see Github repo for more details - https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard and more specifically use the tests as usage samples.